# What does (const char *restrict, ...) mean?

Tags: c, xcode, printf, restrict, restrict-qualifier

When I type `printf`, Xcode give me an autocomplete-hint like `printf(const char *restrict, ...)`.

I want to know what does "const char *restrict mean?
And where can I find more information about these parameters which Xcode throws for every function?

Comment: And best is the authoritative source, for example the C standard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic behind this: Xcode looks at the headers that you included, checks function prototypes, and figures out signatures, and provides you hints as you type based on the prefixes that it sees.

Look at the header documentation for the headers that you include to find out what functions they have, and what are the parameters. For example, `printf` is part of `stdio.h` header, which is documented [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdio.h.html). The signature of `printf` is as follows:

```
int printf(const char *restrict, ...);
```

That is why Xcode suggests `printf(const char *restrict, ...)` for the hint as you type.

Comment: `restrict` is not the name.

Comment: @josh_balmer That's the type of the first parameter. Since `printf` takes a variable number of arguments (as indicated by `...` at the end) Xcode cannot tell you more about parameters the function takes. Other functions, on the other hand, such as `strcmp` or `strncpy`, you would get more hints about the function arguments.